# Spring MVC skips Validator class

Tags: java, spring, validation, tomcat, localhost

Recently I had to take an old project made in Spring MVC. This project have a few JSP pages that insert and update data through a simple form. The controllers of these forms have a validation controller defined into each bean, example:

```
<!-- Controller to add a Local -->
<bean id="addLocalCtrl" class="cl.bbr.portalweb.web.ctrl.AddLocalCtrl">
    <property name="comercio_service" ref="comercioServiceBean"/>
    <property name="usuario_service" ref="usuarioServiceBean"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="command"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="cl.bbr.portalweb.dto.AddLocalDTO"/>
    <property name="validator" ref="addLocalValidator"/>
    <property name="formView" value="add_local"/>
    <property name="successView" value="redirect:adm_local.htm"/>
    <property name="etapa" value="${modelo.etapa}"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Validator Controller -->
<bean id="addLocalValidator"    class="cl.bbr.portalweb.web.validator.AddLocalValidator">
    <property name="comercio_service" ref="comercioServiceBean"/>
    <property name="etapa" value="${modelo.etapa}"></property>
</bean>
```

Validator Class:

```
public class AddLocalValidator implements Validator {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

protected ComerciosService comercio_service = null;
private Integer etapa;

public void setComercio_service(ComerciosService comercio_service) {
    this.comercio_service = comercio_service;
}

public void setEtapa(Integer etapa) {
    this.etapa = etapa;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public boolean supports(Class addLocalClass) {
    return addLocalClass.equals(AddLocalDTO.class);
}

public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
    AddLocalDTO local = (AddLocalDTO) arg0;
```

...etc

This project is already hosted into Apache Tomcat server Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 and JVM 1.7.0_40-b43.

All the classes and validations controllers are written in the same way.

Everything **works fine at server**.

**The problem** **is when** **I test the project at local form**, Spring skips ALL validations and I really don't know why. Even I tried exporting a new WAR file and I up It into the server and WALAH!, the validations works there.

So the problem is when I run the project at localhost.

Local characteristics:

Java 1.8 Tomcat v6.0

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I would do in this situation:

1. Check for any environment variables defined on server and do you have those set up on your local machine.
2. Try to turn on debug or trace statements from your logging framework. It will give you enough information to trace problem. Here is how you can do it: